# Bootstrap: Full width grid with columns in container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, bootstrap-4

I want to create a full width layout with a blue halft on the left and a red half on the right.

After that I want to add text inside the layout but inside a container.

Is this possible?

EDIT: you can see, that the green container has a different size than the col-6 inside the blue and red half.

```css
* {
  color: white;
}
.blue-half {
  background: blue;
}
.red-half {
  background: red;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container green">
  I am the normal container!
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 blue-half">
      <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            I am first half of the blue container!
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            I am second half of the blue container!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 red-half">
      <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            I am first half of the red container!
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            I am second half of the blue container!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here's what I'm reading: "I want a green container to take the first half, and the second half to be split in half (i.e. quarters), and then those halves to be split in half". If that's not quite correct then perhaps create an image of the desired layout and use that as the example?

Comment: Something like this (blue section "Who we are"): https://stripe.com/about - the background of the two half columns should be full width and the content should be in the same width as normal containers in bootstrap.

Comment: That's as simple as using replacing `container-fluid` with `container` and using col-*-12 inside the blue/red half. I'll update my response appropriately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Variant 2. Divide the container into two parts

You can define a new class for each half of the container. But in this solution you needs to control that the two halves have the same height.

```css
.blue { background: blue; color: white; }
.red  { background: red;  color: white; }

.container-left-half,
.container-right-half {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.container-left-half {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.container-right-half {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container-left-half,
  .container-right-half {
    width: 375px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container-left-half,
  .container-right-half {
    width: 485px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container-left-half,
  .container-right-half {
    width: 585px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 blue">
      <div class="container-left-half">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">This is a left half of the container. It's blue! This is a left half of the container. It's blue! This is a left half of the container. It's blue! This is a left half of the container. It's blue! This is a left half of the container. It's blue!</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 red">
      <div class="container-right-half">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">This is a right half of the container. It's red! This is a right half of the container. It's red! This is a right half of the container. It's red! This is a right half of the container. It's red! This is a right half of the container. It's red!</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Variant 1. Linear-gradient & matryoshka

1) You can use [the `linear-gradient()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) to make two-colored background.

2) Bootstrap has [rows](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro) and [two types of containers](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container):

> Use `.container` for a responsive fixed width container.
>
> Use `.container-fluid` for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.
>
> Rows must be placed within a `.container` (fixed-width) or `.container-flui`d (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

3) So you can make a matryoshka:
 `.container-fluid` > `.row with linear-gradient` > `.container` > `.row with content`

> Matryoshka is a set of brightly painted hollow wooden dolls of varying sizes, designed to nest inside one another.

[image: matryoshka]

4) `col-xs-6` is equivalent to `col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6`.

```css
.two-colors {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 50%, red 50%);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row two-colors">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">This is a left half of the container. It's blue! This is a left half of the container. It's blue! This is a left half of the container. It's blue! This is a left half of the container. It's blue! This is a left half of the container. It's blue!</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">This is a right half of the container. It's red! This is a right half of the container. It's red! This is a right half of the container. It's red! This is a right half of the container. It's red! This is a right half of the container. It's red!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The idea with the linear gradient is nice. I've hoped that there would be a solution without a CSS trick. In this version I could only use colors in the background and no images.

Comment: @Simon I've added second variant. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 blue">
        <div class="container">
            <!--content-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 red">
        <div class="container">
            <!--content-->
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
  .red{
    background: red;
   }
  .blue{
    background: blue;
  }
```

Comment: Man, someone always beats me to it!

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it's not exactly what I meant. Now the Content is in a container inside the columns. What I need is the content of both columns combined in a width of a container (centered in the layout). For example: The screensize is 3000px in width. Each column (blue and red). has a width of 1500px. Now I need a container with a witdt of 1140px in the center of the layout and two "col-6" columns in in. I hope you understand what I'm trying to say :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Based on your comment I am reading you want two main columns, red and blue, and then those columns have content centered in them, and that content is also split in half i.e. two more columns within the blue content and red content. Is that correct?

Comment: I made an update to my answer to reflect what I was understanding from your remark. Let me know if that's what you're describing

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```css
* { color: white; }

.blue-half {
  background: blue;
}

.red-half {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 blue-half">
      <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            I am first half of the blue container!
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            I am second half of the blue container!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 red-half">
      <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            I am first half of the red container!
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            I am second half of the red container!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**
I attempted to create what I was reading from your comment regrading the formatting not being quite right

**Update 2**

```css
.row-green {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
.blue-half {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.red-half {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.option1 .row .container {
  padding: 0;
}

.option2 .container.unindent {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid option1">
  <h3>Option 1</h3>
  <p>
    This uses a .row .container selector rule to enforece the padding removal on containers nested in rows.
  </p>
  <div class="row row-green">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      I am the row above!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 blue-half">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            I am the blue container!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 red-half">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            I am the red container!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid option2">
  <h3>Option 2</h3>
  <p>
    This uses an unindent CSS class on the containers that need to have the padding removed
  </p>
  <div class="row row-green">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      I am the row above!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 blue-half">
      <div class="container unindent">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            I am the blue container!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 red-half">
      <div class="container unindent">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            I am the red container!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! But as I wrote in the comment to Damians answer, it is not exactly what I meant. Sorry, maybe my question was a bit unclear.

Comment: thanks again. I also added an example code in my question. You can see, that the start of the content is not in the same line as in the green container. that is what I try to achieve

Comment: So you want "normal container" to be on the same line as the red and blue half containers?

Comment: I really appreciate your help. but the result is still not what I meant. sorry :( the text in the green container is not aligned with the text in the blue container.

Comment: At that point, it's a matter of adjusting the padding. I'll update the sample for you with the two options

Comment: OK, but isn't it always inaccurate if I adjust the padding? I've also found another example: www.getpushforms.com - It seems to be bootstrap but I don't understand it yet

Comment: Adjusting the padding shouldn't cause any major issues as long as your CSS selectors are specific enough to select ONLY the elements that need adjusting, instead of all the elements.

Comment: hmm, but now it's still not in the width of a container. instead the content is full size as well. Maybe my question was to unclear. I've try it again on my own or have to make it clearer what I need. thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">Left Column</div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-expand">Right Column</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-expand {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: orange;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0px;
}
```